# Android Music Player is not detecting Music files

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, partitions, google-play-music, media-scanner

I copied music files from my computer to my Galaxy Nexus phone, using the command `adb push Music /sdcard/Music/`, and the stock Android music player is not detecting these files (while others do). I'm able to view these files in my Android file manager application, but when I mount my phone as an MTP device, the music folder is empty.

Is it related to partitioning? I see two partitions with the same content, `/storage/emulated/0/` and `/storage/emulated/legacy/`.

Comment: The "two partitions" are one and the same: as your device runs Android 4.2 and thus is multi-user capable, the `/storage/emulated/legacy/` simply points to the storage of the currently logged-in user, which is `/storage/emulated/0/`. For the rest, see GAThrawn's answer below: until the *Media Scanner* indexed the new files, the *Music Player* is unable to see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that while `adb push` works to get the files there, it's not the supported way to get media files onto your Android device. This means that it doesn't set the flag that tells the Media Scanner that new media which needs it's meta-data indexed and added to the media library has arrived on your device.

One way to force the media scanner to rescan your storage is to just run an app like [Rescan SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uberullu.rescansd) after you've copied the files over.