# Media scanner will not recognize NEW music

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, music, music-player, media-scanner

So I have a bunch of music already, all in `/sdcard/music` that scans just fine. When I add new music to the folder, the scanner does not recognize it even though I can see them in the folder in My Files. I have ran Rescan SD, it does not help. I am also using the standard Music Player that came with my Droid Charge (2.3.6, I know, it's ancient). Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Yes, all files are `.mp3`, there is no `.nomedia` file in it, ID3 tags are just letters and numbers, and all my music is in `/sdcard/music/`.  This is only happening to new music I've been putting on, all my existing music works fine.

**EDIT:** From what I can gather, it's a problem with the actual scanning feature. The new songs do not show up in other players and rescanning doesn't help either.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is probably a stupid question, but just to confirm: is the new music encoded to a supported such as mp3? (Please [edit] your question with the information)

Comment: Media Scanner in Android will not scan any folder if that folder contains a file named ".nomedia" (without quotes, of course) Check if your desired folders contain any such file. If yes, delete this file and Media Scanner will include those folders in the gallery. With the stock player it won't find music on SD unless sometimes, you can put it in a folder called Music on the root of the SD. then it finds it fine. Lastly check the ID3 tags in the MP3 files, if they have unusual characters they will be skipped!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play Music (KitKat): update library not working](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59176/play-music-kitkat-update-library-not-working)

Comment: You might also want to look at [Winamp not loading new mp3 files](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54873/winamp-not-loading-new-mp3-files/54908#54908)

Comment: It's not a direct duplicate as he is running Android 2.3.6 and not KitKat, but it is worth looking into. The easiest fix is the .nomedia one, unmounting/remounting the SD and the tags. After that it gets a bit messier!

Comment: @bmdixon both questions (rather their answers) do not help here (except for the `.nomedia` part): triggering the media scanner has already been tried, as the OP states in his original question. **domguy:** maybe the media database is "messed up". Try going to *Settings→Apps*, switch to the "All" tab, look for the corresponding apps (not sure which this was on 2.3.6), and delete its data. Then trigger the scanner again (either via *Rescan SD*, or by a reboot). this should re-generate the database contents "from the scratch".

Comment: **Izzy:** Tried doing this, it didn't work either, in multiple music players too.

Comment: See also: [The music player keeps displaying deleted songs. How do I remove them or refresh the library?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10153) and [Android Music Player is not detecting Music files](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45339/) for more on kicking the media scanner into life.

Comment: @Izzy Have you looked to see what logcat says while the media scanner is running? It can usually offer a clue.

Comment: @KenSharp wrong addressee: I'm not the one having the issue :)

Comment: @Izzy Doh! Looked at the "edited" part!

Comment: @domguy Have you looked to see what logcat says while the media scanner is running? It can usually offer a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, It is not a direct answer for your question, but since you are using a "Gingerbread device" that probably uses "mass storage", [Winamp](http://winamp.br.uptodown.com/android) or [MusicPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.music) will do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I mounted and unmounted my SD card, and all apps recognized the files again.